# Get list of Accounts from Contact Email Address

Tags: query, account, contact

Sorry, bit of a noob jumping in at the deep end.

My client has multiple contacts with the same email address. Each contact is linked to a different account.

Is it possible to get a list of all the accounts a contact's email address is connected to? Would someone mind explaining the process or what I would need to query?

Answer (score 1):

For a particular email address, query this: `SELECT Id, AccountId, Account.Name FROM Contact WHERE Email = 'test@example.com'`

Or alternatively you can query accounts: `SELECT Id, Name FROM Account WHERE Id IN (SELECT AccountId FROM Contact WHERE Email = 'test@example.com')`

The best way to visualise the data will be with a Report. You can create Report of type *Contacts & Accounts* and group by the Email field. See my example:

[image]

Comment: Thanks Fred! I will give it a go.

Comment: Did it work? If it did, would you mind accepting my answer?